# Google Cloud Dataflow - is it possible to define a pipeline that reads data from BigQuery and writes to an on-premise database?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow

My organization plans to store a set of data in BigQuery and would like to periodically extract some of that data and bring it back to an on-premise database. In reviewing what I've found online about Dataflow, the most common examples involve moving data in the other direction - from an on-premise database into the cloud. Is it possible to use Dataflow to bring data back out of the cloud to our systems? If not, are there other tools that are better suited to this task?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it lacks sufficient details to create an answer. Clearly specify the problem, what you have tried and any errors. Read this link to help create a good question that can be answered without opinions or guesses about your problem. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Abstractly, yes.  If you've got a set of sources and syncs and you want to move data between them with some set of transformations, then Beam/Dataflow should be perfectly suitable for the task.  It sounds like you're discussing a batch-based periodic workflow rather than a continuous streaming workflow.

In terms of implementation effort, there's more questions to consider. Does an appropriate Beam connector exist for your intended on-premise database?  You can see the built-in connectors here: https://beam.apache.org/documentation/io/built-in/  (note the per-language SDK toggle at top of page)

Do you need custom transformations?  Are you combining data from systems other than just BigQuery?  Either implies to me that you're on the right track with Beam.

On the other hand, if your extract process is relatively straightforward (e.g. just run a query once a week and extract it), you may find there are simpler solutions, particularly if you're not moving much data and your database can ingest data in one of the BigQuery [export formats](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data#export_formats_and_compression_types).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Per the comment on my original question, I realize I've failed to provide much detail. I have not experimented at all yet, because we're still evaluating feasibility. I might try to simplify my question by asking "Does the Dataflow technology on GCP permit writing to data stores that do not themselves reside on GCP." Not surprisingly, the common examples focus on the opposite direction - getting data into GCP. So, it was not clear to me if the technology was fundamentally limited to work in this direction. Regardless, thank you both for your feedback.